# outData.txt not outputting the correct values

Tags: c++, file-io, input, outputstream, fileoutputstream

I am having trouble taking a # from inData.txt and outputting the value into outData.txt
The values that are in my inData.txt are:
10.20 5.35

The values that appear in my outData.txt are:
Rectangle:
Length= -92559631349317830000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00, Width= -92559631349317830000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00, Area= 8567285355521621000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00, Perimeter= -370238525397271320000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00

Here is my code(Right now I am just working on outputting the length, width, area, and perimeter )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main ()

{
// Filestream Variable declaration

ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;

// Variable Declaration

double length, width, areaOfRectangle, perimeter, radius, areaOfCircle,           beginningBalance, interestRate, pi,
       circumference, endingBalance;
string firstName, lastName;
 int   age;
 char  ch;

// Opening Filestream Variables

 inFile.open("inData.txt");
 outFile.open("outData.txt");

 // Data Manipulation

 outFile << fixed << showpoint;
 outFile << setprecision(2);

 cout << "Processing Data..." << endl;

 // Variable Association


 inFile >> length >> width;
 outFile <<"Rectangle:" << endl;
 areaOfRectangle = length * width;
 perimeter = (length * 2) + (width * 2);
 outFile <<"Length= " << length << ", Width= " << width << ", Area= " << areaOfRectangle << ", Perimeter= " << perimeter << endl;





 // Closing Filestream Variables

 inFile.close();
 outFile.close();






return 0;

    }
```

Comment: You never check your inputs for success. How can you be sure they were read correctly?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can check `inFile >> length >> width;` in a boolean context. It will be false if it failed to read either one.

Comment: Well then how do I make it read it correctly?

Comment: I'd start with making sure those .open()'s worked.

Comment: Try absolute paths. Relative paths tend to cause unexpected errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    // Filestream Variable declaration
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    // Variable Declaration
    double length, width, areaOfRectangle, perimeter, radius, areaOfCircle, beginningBalance, interestRate, pi,
       circumference, endingBalance;
    string firstName, lastName;
    int age;
    char ch;

    // Opening Filestream Variables
    inFile.open("inData.txt");
    outFile.open("outData.txt");

    if(inFile.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Error opening inData.txt" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if(outFile.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Error opening outData.txt" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Data Manipulation
    outFile << fixed << showpoint;
    outFile << setprecision(2);

    cout << "Processing Data..." << endl;

    // Variable Association
    if(!(inFile >> length >> width)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to read values." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    outFile <<"Rectangle:" << endl;
    areaOfRectangle = length * width;
    perimeter = (length * 2) + (width * 2);
    outFile <<"Length= " << length << ", Width= " << width << ", Area= " << areaOfRectangle << ", Perimeter= " << perimeter << endl;

    // Closing Filestream Variables
    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DavidCamacho Try the new code I just updated, it'll tell you whether it's trouble reading or opening.

Comment: @DavidCamacho, Again, check to make sure they were opened successfully. They might not be found, among other possibilities.

Comment: @chris If he runs the new code it'll tell him if it failed to open.

Comment: Then you need to double check the contents of inData.txt.

Comment: Do you think I should try it on another computer?
Other than that is my code correct?

Comment: If you're on Windows 7 or Vista, I've had known issues with the access management system allowing me to access local files. 

IF that is the case of the OS, you may have to right click and run as administrator to test, versus run from the IDE.

Comment: @M4rc Are you saying it would allow you to open the file but then mess up the read?

Comment: @DavidCamacho I have tested your code on my computer and it seems to work fine. Output: `Rectangle:
Length= 10.20, Width= 5.35, Area= 54.57, Perimeter= 31.10` which is why we all decided it was a file issue.

Comment: Yeah. Almost like an access sharing violation, but obviously not. Windows 7 for what ever reason seems to have general issues with how some simple stuff operates. For that reason, I always put it in compatibility mode with XP SP2 and run as administrator before debugging. Not saying that's CERTAINLY the case, but I've known it to happen.

Comment: Yeah I have win 7 and I chose to run MSVS c++ as admin but still.
I'll try it on another computer'

Comment: @M4rc Yeah, I mean I'm not disagree about the running it as admin in general, but it just seems so odd that it would open and fail to read (leave it to microsoft to really screw stuff up though).

Comment: Ok does it matter if I wrote my numbers in notepad from left to right or top to bottom. Either way I already tried both but nothing

Comment: @CrazyCasta I completely understand -- I got windows 7 last year I believe, and I tried running programs I wrote on it that were perfect in Windows XP, just to do arbitrary stuff [Encryption, tile set cutting] and was surprised on how many stopped responding or spat out wrong values; yet on the exact same files on windows XP partition worked without issue.

Comment: @DavidCamacho - How about instead of using infile's extraction operator, you use `infile.getline(temp, 256, ' ');`, with temp as a `char *`, just to see if it's the extraction operator operating funky.
Because the code looks like it should be doing the right thing, though the only other thing I can think of is that you're reading it into a `double` versus a `char *` or `std::string`, but that doesn't sound like it should be an issue.

Comment: Thing is that we haven't learned that in class yet so I can't come up with .getline( , ) lol
I mean if it's working for you then it's obviously right.
I'll try it at my computer lab at school

Comment: I don't know of many teachers that don't like when people research on the topic to find other answers; granted my college professors were pretty lax. >> should work.. It works on my run and on CrazyCasta's as well.

Comment: Yeah I'll try it on another computer. 
Thanks for sticking with me guys
THis website is very reliable
(Not to do my homework but whenever I really don't know what I'm doing wrong)